# google adwords php api - individual product statistics reporting

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I'm using GoogleAds PHP api and basically what I want to do is to get individual statistics for products in a certain account (ad groups):

[image: Sample report]

Is it possible to generate a report that is similar to the image above? Or is it the correct way to get individual product statistics (ctr, conversions, clicks,etc) or is there any other way to do it? I'm not asking for complete solution. I just want a guide to follow along because it seems that there's no available resource to read about this. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm hoping someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: what are you trying to say? :)

Comment: :D I thought you have ideas for this :) thanks anyways

Comment: I think this is not really possible :/